# Adding only unique values to a table array in django

Tags: python, django, pymongo

I am trying to use an array in a table, and want to insert values into the array only if the array doesnt already contain the value. I am not sure what would be the best approach for performance here.

"models.py"

```
class Documents(models.Model):
documentID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

class VisibleDocuments(models.Model):
    visibleTo = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, null=True)
    documents = ListField()
```

When I add documents to visibleDocuments, I do the following:

"views.py"

```
visibleDocuments.documents.append(document.documentID)
visibleDocuments.save()
```

However, the problem with this approach is that it leads to duplicate documentIDs in the list. I would like to have only unique documentIDs. I wonder what would be the best way to do that in Django? Can I use sets perhaps or should I use some kind of sorted read access, perhaps?

Thanks in advance!

Solution: Use SetField

```
class VisibleDocuments(models.Model):
    visibleTo = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, null=True)
    documents = SetField()
```

views.py

```
visibleDocuments.documents.add(document.documentID)
visibleDocuments.save()
```

Thanks to everybody!

Comment: http://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/lists-and-dicts.html     . Your question was helpful, I found setField in the link above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that ListField is the ListField from djangotoolbox, you should consider using SetField instead.

Comment: Thanks, I just found that out and was able to use it successfully

Answer (score 1):

Crude python way of doing this:

```
if document.documentID not in visibleDocuments.documents:
    visibleDocuments.documents.append(document.documentID)
```